# How to handle app minimization separately of activity switch

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onresume

I have an app in which when user opens it for the first time or after returning from another app it must ask him for a password. So i've created Enter Password Activity in which user enters password and moves to the main activity and set EP Activity to the starting activity. Then i thought to put call of Enter Password Activity in onRestart() method, it works when i return to my app from another app, but it also triggers when i return to main activity from another activity. And that is incorrect. I need  Enter Password Activity to pop up only if i'm returning to my app "from outside".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewClickListener {

    /../

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnterPasswordActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /../
    }

    /../

    @Override
    public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position) {
        String item = apps.get(position).getName();
        // This is the switch to second activity in app, and i must return 
        // from it witout entering password again
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailedAppInfoActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("appName", item);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And my Enter Password Activity

```
public class EnterPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText enterPass;
    Button button;

    String pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_password);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
        pass = settings.getString("password","");

        enterPass = findViewById(R.id.mainPassEditText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.confirmPassButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String enteredPass = enterPass.getText().toString();
                if(enteredPass.equals(pass)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(EnterPasswordActivity.this,"Incorrect password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I've read [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-detect-android-application-open-and-close-background-and-foreground-events-1b4713784b57), and now i have control on my app going to foreground and back. But now where do i call startActivity()? I cant call it from App class, it says "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to track the even when your app comes to foreground, to do that you need to track Application Lifecycle events. For that you will need to create an Handler class to detect the Background and foreground state of you app, an Application class to take action.

This [blog](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-detect-android-application-open-and-close-background-and-foreground-events-1b4713784b57) will help you to track that event

Comment: I've read this article and now i have control on my app going  to foreground and back. But now where do i call startActivity()? I cant call it from App class, it says "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Comment: Add Flag
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: How critical it is to add a flag?